# ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'

Tags: java, r, rjava

Tried installing rJava on R but getting this error

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rJava/rJava_0.9-9.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

**Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rJava'**

Installed jdk-18.0.1.1 and also set environment variables like this

JAVA_HOME: C:\Users\H481821\Downloads\openjdk-18.0.1.1_windows-x64_bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed environment path from

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\Users\H481821\Downloads\openjdk-18.0.1.1_windows-x64_bin
to
C:\Users\H481821\Downloads\openjdk-18.0.1.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-18.0.1.1
```

and executed R cmd

```
install.packages("rJava", type="win.binary")
```

(Use this to get compatible package to you R version so that you won't face version issues)